# Why is the phrase "Winter is coming" so significant in Game of Thrones?

Tags: game-of-thrones

I am curious as to what the phrase "Winter is coming" might mean in *Game of Thrones*.

I know about the thing with the White Walker. Is there anything I am missing? What actually is going to happen when the winter comes? Does the winter signify the season or is it something different?